# Convert array to string in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I want to convert an array to string in NodeJS.

```
var aa = new Array();
aa['a'] = 'aaa';
aa['b'] = 'bbb';

console.log(aa.toString());
```

But it doesn't work.
Anyone knows how to convert?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You're using an `Array` like an "associative array", which does not exist in JavaScript. Use an `Object` (`{}`) instead.

If you are going to continue with an array, realize that `toString()` will join all the **numbered** properties together separated by a comma. (the same as `.join(",")`).

Properties like `a` and `b` will not come up using this method because they are not in the **numeric** indexes. (ie. the "body" of the array)

In JavaScript, Array inherits from `Object`, so you can add and delete properties on it like any other object. So for an array, the numbered properties (they're technically just strings under the hood) are what counts in methods like `.toString()`, `.join()`, etc. Your other properties are still there and very much accessible. :)

Read [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for more information about Arrays.

```
var aa = [];

// these are now properties of the object, but not part of the "array body"
aa.a = "A";
aa.b = "B";

// these are part of the array's body/contents
aa[0] = "foo";
aa[1] = "bar";

aa.toString(); // most browsers will say "foo,bar" -- the same as .join(",")
```

Answer (score 20):

`toString` is a method, so you should add parenthesis `()` to make the function call.

```
> a = [1,2,3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> a.toString()
'1,2,3'
```

Besides, if you want to use strings as keys, then you should consider using a `Object` instead of `Array`, and use `JSON.stringify` to return a string.

```
> var aa = {}
> aa['a'] = 'aaa'
> JSON.stringify(aa)
'{"a":"aaa","b":"bbb"}'
```

Comment: Type mistake for the parenthesis. It's corrected. Can you explain why use Object for the string as keys. Why Array can't not be use? And why Object.toString() not work?

Comment: @Magic see this great post: http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 12):

toString is a function, not a property. You'll want this:

```
console.log(aa.toString());
```

Alternatively, use join to specify the separator (toString() === join(','))

```
console.log(aa.join(' and '));
```

Answer (score 3):

In node, you can just say

```
console.log(aa)
```

and it will format it as it should.

If you need to use the resulting string you should use

```
JSON.stringify(aa)
```

Comment: JSON.stringify(aa) can't print the content. Because my array is string index. It only work for int index array.

Comment: @Magic - There's no such thing as a string index array in js. The only reason aa['a'] works is because the Array type inherits from Object, so it will emulate an associative array, while in fact a lot of the array functions will no longer work because of it, and there are other pitfalls. If you need associative array, you should use an object `{a:0, b:4}` instead of the array type, which only really works on numeric indexes `[0,4]`

Answer (score 0):

You can also cast an array to a string like...

```
newStr = String(aa);
```

I also agree with Tor Valamo's answer, console.log should have no problem with arrays, no need to convert to a string unless you're debugging something or just curious.