# Node JS returning Objects, How to check what is inside

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working with the Google adwords API and i am getting a result like this :

```
null { totalNumEntries: 700,
  entries:
   [ { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] },
     { data: [Object] } ] }
```

With this code:

```
var targetingIdeaService = user.getService('TargetingIdeaService', 'v201705')

//create selector 
var selector = {
  searchParameters: [{
    'xsi:type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
    queries: ['test']
  }],
  ideaType: 'KEYWORD',
  requestType: 'IDEAS',
  requestedAttributeTypes: ['KEYWORD_TEXT'],
  paging: {
    startIndex: 0,
    numberResults: 12
  }

};

targetingIdeaService.get({
  selector: selector
}, function(error, result) {
  console.log(error, result);
})
```

How can i check what is inside the object?

Comment: Do you want to pretty print the object to the terminal?

Comment: that would be an array,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907094/convert-array-to-string-in-nodejs

Comment: @yev yeah in the terminal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pretty print the object to the terminal, use:

```
var string = JSON.stringify(object)

// or JSON.stringify(object, null, 2) to make it more readable

console.log(string)
```

Comment: Thanks really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You can use

var string = JSON.stringify(object,null,4)

There are plenty of variety you can use stringify in javascript. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
var util = require('util');

console.log(util.inspect(result, { depth: null }));
```